# Lower FPS than expected on laptop

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, cpu, performance

Hope I am in the right place for this one.

I recently bought a new laptop. It is not a gaming laptop and I don't intend to  use it that way, but I expected more than what it seems to be capable of. This is the link from where I got it :

https://www.netonnet.se/art/dator-surfplatta/laptop/laptop-10-13-tum/asus-zenbook-ux331fn-em052t/1011339.8906/

It has :

- i5-8265U processor
- 8 GB of RAM
- Nvidia GeForce MX150-2 graphics card.

Comparing it to my old laptop with :

- i5-8250U processor
- 8 GB of RAM
- NVIDIA Quadro P600 Graphics card

When looking at benchmarks, my new laptop should be a bit better but for some reason it is not. I tested it on Heroes & Generals which produced around 30 fps compared to my old 60-70 fps. I tested it on lowest settings in Minecraft and could only get around 40 fps even though I recall my old one getting around 70-80 on highest settings.

I've gone through all settings and made sure everything is set to "High performance". I have checked that it is not my Integrated graphics that is being used but my MX150 as it should be, and even gone through the settings in NVIDIA control panel.

I can't figure out what is going on. If anyone has an idea of something I could try I would be gratefull. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Has the new laptop a higer resolution screen than the old one?

Comment: No, its the same @Hennes

Comment: Although not designed for gaming, a Quadro P600 is a much faster card than an MX150 for 3D work [though neither is stellar] You also got a slower i5 in the new machine than you had in the old one. Basically, you bought a slower computer than the one you had.

Comment: I don't know much about the GPUs but it could make sense. But shouldn't the i5-8265U be the better CPU? @Tetsujin [link](https://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i5-8265U-vs-Intel-Core-i5-8250U/m566107vsm338266)

Comment: I used https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu_list.php & http://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu_list.php

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that the GeForce MX150-2 card is not used by the game, and instead the integrated graphics card is used - Intel UHD Graphics 620.

Make sure that the drivers are installed and the card is set as default.

Comment: As I have said, I have made sure that my MX150-2 graphics card is the one in use

Comment: I mentioned it just in case, because I had a laptop on which I selected the card by default but the game would keep using the Intel one. I noticed this because some games show the graphics card used in the game options.

Comment: In NVIDIA settings, you have the abillity to activate "GPU Activity" so I can see if my graphics card is being used and also by which programs. Thanks anyways! @CrazyEyesDave